DataTables - Scroll to column text starting with <key pressed>
Hi All I did my best with the title, the issue I am having is I dont know how to approach this task. I have a datatable with 1000s of rows displayed on one page with ScrollY limit. The datatable is sorted alphabetically by the second column (Accounts), this column displays Account Code text.
When focused on the table I want to be able to press any letter key for example 'L' and auto scroll to the start of all Account Codes beginning with that letter if that makes sense?
I understand how to scroll to a specific place on the table container but not how to ask a specific row position in terms of scrollTop value

Once you have the row element, you can call getBoundingClientRect() to get it's x, y location to use for your scrolling
